# How tell a user has changed the value on a control in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a form with bunch of NSTextFields, Date Pickers and a NSPopupButton. I want to provide the save functionality only if user has changed the values of those controls. So how can I track the changes in cocoa? I thought of analyzing the value properties of each control using Key Value Observing however then it would trigger notifications for programmatically assigned values such as default values. So any ideas how to handle this situation ?

Comment: You can use KVO to detect when a value changes. If that is not what you need then please be more specific.

Comment: No I want to detect whether user has changed the values on those fields. KVO will trigger notifications even for the values that assigned programmatically as I explained in the question.

Comment: If you are assigning the values programmatically you could stop unregister for the notifications and then when you have finished setting the values reregister for KVO.

Comment: Good point ! It didn't occur to me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

For your text fields, make your window or view controller the fields' delegate, then implement `-controlTextDidChange:`, and enable saving there. If you need to take different actions depending on which textfield is edited, you can retrieve it from the passed-in notification object.

NSPopupButtons are buttons, so they use the target:action pattern. Implement an IBAction method in your controller, then connect your popup button(s) to it. You can use the same action method for multiple popup buttons if you do the same thing for each one (e.g. simply enable the save button and/or menu item).

You may still get spurious notifications when setting default values for your controls, depending how you go about it. If so, simply add a BOOL property to your controller, called `changeTrackingDisabled` or similar. Set it to YES when setting your default values (or reverting to the last saved state), set it back to NO when finished. Then in each method that notices changes, check the state of that property.

Personally I feel using delegates and actions is a more effective approach than KVO in this case. KVO's API [leaves something to be desired](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/key-value-observing-done-right.html), and tends to increase coupling between components because you must statically encode the path of all properties you wish to observe using strings. [This blog post](http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/06/14/delegation-notification-and-observation/) has a nice, in-depth discusson of the pros & cons.